# Any code after DynamicParam block on the script level is parsed as syntax error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use *DynamicParam* on the script level. All examples on the internet show function level. As long as I have no code after the DynamicParam {}, it works (I can stop inside the block in debugger), however any code added after is a syntax error. I've seen some advise that begin/process/end should be used and I tried that and it did not have any affect.

I have this for proof of concept:

**MyScript.ps1**

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
 [parameter()]
 [string] $a,

 [parameter()]
 [string] $b,

 [parameter()]
 [string] $c
)
DynamicParam
{
  if($a -match 'aaa') 
  {
     # .......
     # creates dynamic param here
     # .......
  }
}

# Anything below this line is not accepted by powershell parser
# Next line will cause powershell to generate: "Unexpected token '$x' in expression or statement" error.
$x = 10
```

If I add:

```
begin {}
process {}
end {}
```

I still cannot add any code after.

Perhaps some silly mistake I cannot see; I am stuck.

Powershell version:

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion
Major Minor Build Revision
----- ----- ----- ---------
4      0    -1    -1
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce, however it should be noted that if you declare dynamicparam you must declare one of begin, process and end. And your code must live within one of those blocks. You cannot put code beneath end (for example).

Comment: Thank you Chris. Yes, I did not realize that the rest of the script should be inside the process block. Does having process {} implies some additional requirement/impact? My understanding was that it is used to support pipe line.

Comment: By default code you would have placed after param executes in the end block. An undeclared means of helping out if you like. Pushing code into process allows you to support a pipeline but this is by no means mandatory. In theory you should not put code in process if you have no intention of supporting a pipeline. if someone were to feed it a pipeline it would execute the block once for each input object regardless of whether or not you consume that input object. e.g. `function test { process { 'bob' } }; Get-ChildItem | test`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So if I do not plan to support a pipe, I can just put my code inside the end{}.

Comment: Yep, that would do nicely. One final caveat if you do, should you flag a parameter as accepting pipeline input later, the values in such a parameter will only be available to the process block, not begin or end.

Comment: Yep, understood. Thanks Chris. I did not expect the problem to be solved so quickly :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `DynamicParam` block is used, PowerShell expects your code to be inside of at least one of the `Process`, `Begin`, or `End` blocks. So your script might look like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
 [parameter()]
 [string] $a,

 [parameter()]
 [string] $b,

 [parameter()]
 [string] $c
)
DynamicParam
{
  if($a -match 'aaa') 
  {
     # .......
     # creates dynamic param here
     # .......
  }
}

Process 
{
# Anything below this line is not accepted by powershell parser
$x = 10 # This will cause powershell to generate: "Unexpected token '$x' in expression or statement"
}
```

Comment: Hi @M.K., if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.